# Rails preference tables and over-riding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wondering what the best way is to go about the following design problem:

I have a User which will have a Preferences table. I will also have a Venue, which belongs to a user. I want the following functionality:

A Venue will have preferences, all of which will be set in the Preference table belonging to the user. I want these to be the "default" preferences. However, each individual Venue can override these preferences.

Single table inheritance? Separate models and simply check for existence of the "Venue Preferences?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a user's default preferences and a user's specific venue preferences have the same exact attributes, this seems like a good candidate for single table inheritance. So, Preferences would have both a user id as well as a venue id. Then, in order to determine what the actual preferences for a venue will be, you'd first check to see if there are preferences for that venue. Otherwise, default to the user's preferences.